# Localizing TYPO3 using XLIFF

Tags: localization, typo3, xliff

I want to automatically generate an xliff file each time I change labels in TYPO3. I want this file to be placed in a shareable drive. When I translate the xliff file , I want TYPO3 to automaticatlly populate the webpage with this translation. Is this possible?

I haven't tried anything yet, I am just looking for a starting point. I have read TYPO3 documentation on xliff.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you could realize it this way.

But you can do something like this:
instead of using constant strings for labels use referenzces of XLIFF entries like `LLL:EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf` so TYPO3 always(*) will look into the language files for a label.

All label changes need to be done in the language files and are used automatically(*)

On your server you might map that folder to a sharable folder (but don't forget: you need to clear Caches to get modification in the FrontEnd).

(*) Disclaimer:
as TYPO3 caches the language files you need to clear system caches to get the newest labels.